# How do you wire up a ASP.NET MVC 5 UserManager instance with Autofac?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-mvc-5

With the MVC 5 release comes the Asp.Net.Identity bits including the UserManager. Instantiation can get messy and I'm trying to add with Autofac controller settings.

Controller's constructor

```
public LoginController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
}
```

Manually creating a new instance:

```
var controller = new LoginController(UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationUserStore<ApplicationUser>(new MyDbContext())));
```

ApplicationUserStore class/constructor:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore<TUser> : IUserLoginStore<TUser>, IUserStore<TUser>, IDisposable where TUser : ApplicationUser

public ApplicationUserStore(IMyDbContext context)
{
    Context = context;
}
```

I have new for the db context working correctly:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().As<IMyDbContext>();
```

What would be the registration signature for the LoginController?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know AutoFac, but wild guess:

```
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserStore<ApplicationUser>>()
    .As<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
builder.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Comment: Good guess! I updated the question to include the ApplicationUserStore class definition, because it implements more than IUserStore. But, for this case, basing the Autofac registration on the fact that it implements IUserStore is good enough I think.  Thanks.

Comment: Right, it implements IUserRoleStore, IUserPasswordStore, etc, but UserManager only needs the IUserStore as an argument. It then tries to detect support for the other interfaces internally.